# whether we should compress images/decompress images in both ends when 800/900 KB photo is uploaded to server?

Tags: iphone, upload, dropbox, photos

We need some good suggestions to improve the time for uploading photos to server(current we use dropbox, but we open to other option such as amazon S3.. etc)

When user take the photo, we encrypted the photos and upload it to dropbox/or our own server, but the photo size is 800/900 KB, and it take more than a minutes to finish it,

Currently we are exploring other option such as compression/decompression in both ends, and we are not sure whether it is worth compressing/decompressing the photos in order to save the time for uploading.

Any good suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a FAT pipe to your own dedicated server (maybe EC2 -> S3) it would help.  The bottleneck here would be bandwidth, but you do not want to slow it down by doing compression on something that would not compress well.  Many images types are well compressed already.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your customer has rather fast 10mbit/s cable or DSL connection, uploading 1GB file will take about 1000 seconds, or almost 20 minutes. In practice it is even worse - most connections are asymmetric. For example, it is typical to have 10mbit/s download speed and only 1mbit/s upload speed. For your case, it would mean that time to upload 1GB file will be over 3 hours.

It does not matter what you use on server side - dropbox, S3 or any combination of them, or even use multiple parallel streams - your bottleneck is your internet connection.

Most images are already heavily compressed, and it is not very likely that you will gain anything by trying to compress them.

In other words, you really need to rethink your approach - do you REALLY want user to download 1GB image to your server in first place? Would it be sufficient to download only thumbnail of typical size of high-quality picture (5-10MB), and only then slowly upload uber-quality giant picture?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really gain a lot by compressing images and you risk corrupting the image.  800-900 MB images are almost certainly tifs or something where the resolution is important.  The most important factor is just plain bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the question has been edited to say kilobytes instead of megabytes... :-)

Uploading a photo that's less than 1MB shouldn't take a minute on a typical internet connection. As others have said, photos generally don't compress well, so it's unlikely you would see much of a performance gain by compressing first.